# Detect when user focus on browser address bar

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

In a browser extension, is it possible to detect when a user focuses on the browser address bar?

I would like to copy what a user is writing in the address browser bar and paste it somewhere else in my browser extension.|
I couldn't find any documentation neither in chrome nor in MDN

Any tips are highly appreciated!

Comment: No, there's no such API. The closest one is [chrome.omnibox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The Omnibox is just in the case a user types a specific keyword, listed by me in the manifest beforeahead, correct?